# How do I get system default checkbox BITMAP in VS2015?

Tags: checkbox, bitmap, mfc, ownerdrawn, cmenu

I want to get the system's default checkbox for to display it in an owner-drawn MFC menu.
I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486740/how-do-i-get-the-default-check-box-images), but that did not answer my question.

I want to implement this line:

```
hbmpCheckboxes = LoadBitmap((HINSTANCE) NULL, 
        (LPTSTR) OBM_CHECKBOXES);
```

which I got from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647558(v=vs.85).aspx), section 
*Simulating Check Boxes in a Menu*

I get this error: *Error    C2065   'OBM_CHECKBOXES': undeclared identifier*
If I define it myself: `#define OBM_CHECKBOXES      32759`, and I run the code, then LoadBitmap returns a handle. In VS2015 I see this: `hbmpCheckboxes 0xc305143c {unused=??? }`, so to me it seems an invalid bitmaphandle is returned. I think there is more missing than just the OBM_CHECKBOXES define, but I can't figure out what.

- Is there a file I should include?
- Is there a DLL which I need to link
  against?
- Is there a project setting I should set?
- Or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbitmap-class#loadoembitmap).

You want to use `CBitmap::LoadOEMBitmap` and note the comment at the bottom:

> Note that the constant **OEMRESOURCE** must be defined before including WINDOWS.H in order to use any of the OBM_ constants.

Comment: Nice answer! Not needed, but just commenting for my future reference!